# Platform privilege in tizen

Tags: tizen

How do I use platform privileges in tizen?

I am adding platform privileges through a manifest file and running my application, and I am getting an error like:

> Error code: INVALID_PRIVILEGE
>   Error message: Thrown when unauthorized privileges are detected. [partner] or [platform] signing is required.

Please guide me as to how to use platform privileges. Is there anything that should be done in order to use such privileges?

Comment: To use platform priviliges you must have special certifcate that probably is available only for "partners" right now. Maybe there is also option to obtain such certificate if you're commercial seller, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

I found platform level privilege for IDE. Check the link:

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/tizen_overview/platform_privileges.htm

Comment: can you please tell me where is Git repo for `hash-signer/certificates` directory. I looked at [http://download.tizen.org/](http://download.tizen.org/) but was not able to find the certificate.